# file / folder permissions - dotnet building on windows but deploy to linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing and building asp.net core on a Windows machine but will be running on a linux box (ubuntu).

this is a small side project - i will just be building the folder in release mode from visual studio and then manually FTP'ing over to the server.

Are there any steps required with setting folder or file permissions? I recall reading somewhere that files created on windows and copied to linux will permissions open by default?

Answer (score 0):

By default, file system permissions on Linux are a bit more restrictive than on Windows. This will usually only affect *write* access though. If you copy files over via FTP, they will be usually created in a way that all users on the target machine are able to read the files.

That also means that the service which is executing your application on your Linux machine is likely already allowed to access those files and as such is able to execute them via the .NET runtime (with the `dotnet` executable).

You may need to pay extra attention to permissions if you are in any of the following situations:

- You publish the application as a self-contained application, with the runtime bundled in. In this case, you don’t have a global `dotnet` executable on your machine that is executing the application but there will be an executable within the distributed files of your application. You may need to set the executable permission flag for this file in order to allow your service user to run your application. You will quickly notice this though when you try to run the application since it will fail immediately.
- If your application writes to the file system, for example to save file uploads of users or if you are having file-based databases (e.g. SQLite), then the service user will need write access to the folder or files that it needs to access. These write flags will not be set by default so you will need to do this manually yourself when deploying your application. Problems of these kinds will fail at *runtime*, so you should verify early if you need write access for anything.